# How to dot a await message collector with 2 question

Tags: javascript, async-await, discord.js

I would like to pose 2 questions after bann a user

1. !bann @user
2. Reason why
3. how much time.

I think I can do that with await message. In this code, I can do just 2 collectors, how can I add an other please ?

```
message.channel.send('Why you want to bann this user ?')
.then(async() => {
    message.channel.awaitMessages(response => message.content, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ['time'],
  })
  .then(async(collected) => {
      message.channel.send(`The collected message was: ${collected.first().content}`);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      message.channel.send('There was no collected message that passed the filter within the time limit!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to make your message handler an async function, then use async/await:

```js
await message.channel.send("Why do you want to ban this user?");
const reason = (await message.channel.awaitMessages(res => message.content, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ["time"]
})).first().content;
await message.channel.send("For how long do you want to ban them?");
const time = (await message.channel.awaitMessages(res => message.content, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ["time"]
})).first().content;
```

Then, you can access the responses in the `reason` and `time` variables.

Comment: Men, I would like to know how can I delete await message time and reason ? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: @RjjfjfkFkkfkf Get rid of the `.content`, that way `reason` and `time` contain the messages, then you can just `await reason.delete()` and `await time.delete()`, but then you need to access their conents with `reason.content` and `time.content`